# Scala Play framework - cannot find static resources

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, static-resource

I am new to Scala Play Framework. In my routes I have mentioned my the url to all my static resources. Here is the code for it.

```
GET    /public/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/", file)
```

My application context is `/api/dashboard/v2.2`. I have a public folder in the root of my project. There is an html page called `default.htm`. Now I want to see the html page in the browser.

In the url I am typing ***http://localhost:9000/api/dashboard/v2.2/public/default.htm***. It is giving me ***404 Not Found*** error. The call to the methods of the controller are working fine. But whenever I am trying to call the static resources I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an Route in your route file located at conf/route

add a route default route.

```
GET          /yoururl              controllers.Application.default
```

Move your file to views folder and save it as `default.scala.html`.

Make a controller Application controller in your controller folder.

```
import play.api.mvc._
object Application extends Controller {

  def default = Action {
    Ok("views.html.default()")
  }

}
```

Type In Browser `"http://localhost:9000/yoururl"`
It will render your default HTML page.

Comment: what about my application conext?

Comment: what you are suggesting contradicts with https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
http://localhost:9000/public/default.htm
```

where page location

```
Project-->public--->default.htm
```

Comment: what about my application context?

Comment: I have tried what you are suggesting. It says action not found

Comment: you can define your application context in your conf file as : application.context="/api/dashboard/v2.2"

Comment: then what is the error you are getting if you could elaborate it more, it will be more helpful.

Comment: @curious  the error i am getting is not found error. I believe it means is that the application is unable to find the "/public/default.htm" file.

Comment: I have edited my ans , move your default.html file to views folder and look my ans for clarification.

Comment: @eddard.stark with the way I described you can access the static file directly from browser without an routes(apart from the routes described in your question) or controller action.But with this there is no role controller and to access view with dynamic data create a `/app/view/default.scala.html` and calll it from controller.And if you are new then check the sample applications that play provided